# Staging function and printing results to cells VBA

Tags: function, vba, excel, logic

Essentially I have an array `A = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` what I want to do is, with the use of `Rnd()`, circle around this loop depending on the value of the random numbers.

Basically start at `0 Mod 5` get a random number. If the random number is less than 0.5 then I stay at `0 Mod 5`, however if the random number is greater than or eual to 0.5 then I move to `1 Mod 5`, then because it's passed to the next stage 'it gets to roll again', so I pass a new random number to it, to see if it can get to `2 Mod 5`.

My aim is to run this 10,000 times and collect the results in the A column in a spreadsheet and then plot a scattergraph to see how it works.

Now I created a function

```
Function looper(R, i)
If R < 0.5 Then
    j = i
Else
    j = i + 1
End If
If j = i Then
    Exit Function
Else
    newR = Rnd()
    j = looper(newR, j)
End If
End Function
```

Coupled with the sub

```
Sub loopy()
A = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Randomize
R = Rnd()
k = looper(R, 1)
Cells(1, 1).Value = A(k Mod 5)
```

However it only ever returns the value 1.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, either with my logic, or how I'm attempting to put my logic into VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to analyse and/or crack an online roulette logic? ;)

---

Your `looper` function is designed to always return `1`. 
Even if the random number is greater than `0.5` you are calling the function recursively - so, in easy words, it repeats until the new random number is smaller than `0.5` and if it is then it returns `1`.

So I rewrote this for you and this code will print out the results of `how many random numbers greater than 0.5 can I get in a row` - in column A. 
It prints the number of stages it passes

```
Option Explicit

Sub roulette()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, nextRow&, i&, max&
    Set ws = Sheets(1): ws.Cells.ClearContents
    For max = 1 To 10001
        nextRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws.Range("A" & max).Value = getStage
    Next max
End Sub

Function crack() As Boolean
    Dim x#: Randomize: x = Rnd()
    If x >= 0.5 Then crack = True
End Function

Function getStage() As Long
    Dim cnt&
    While crack: cnt = cnt + 1: Wend: getStage = cnt
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I changed my function

```
Function looper(i)
R = Rnd()
If R < 0.5 Then
    looper = i
Else
    looper = i + 1
End If
End Function
```

and altered my sub

```
Sub loopy()
A = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Number"
For i = 2 To 10001
    k = 1
    j = 1
    While k = j
        j = looper(k)
        k = k + 1
    Wend
    Cells(i, 1).Value = A(j Mod 5)
Next i
End Sub
```

This gives me what I want. I'm now hoping however, that some bright spark can conceieve of a better method that doesn't involve a `While` loop that I've always been taught should be avoided wherever possible.